# Using a grid table to estimate a limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider finding the limit of $f(x)=(x^2-4)/(x-2)$ as $x\to 2$.

```
f[x_] := (x^2 - 4)/(x - 2);
```

I'm looking for some easy ways for my Calc I students (next semester) to approximate the limit of this function as x approaches two. I know about Limit[f[x],x->2], but my first interest is creating a table of values that indicates an estimate of the limit. I have a couple approaches for approaching two from the right.

First:

```
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, {2.1, 2.01, 2.001, 2.0001, 2.00001}}];
PrependTo[data, {"x", "f(x)"}];
Grid[data,
 Alignment -> Left,
 Frame -> All]
```

Second:

```
data = Table[{2. + 10^(-n), f[2. + 10^(-n)]}, {n, 1, 5}];
PrependTo[data, {"x", "f(x)"}];
Grid[data,
 Alignment -> Left,
 Frame -> All]
```

Anybody have some cuter, easier suggestions?

Comment: For `{2.1, 2.01, 2.001, 2.0001, 2.00001}` you can do `2. + PowerRange[10^-1, 10^-5, 0.1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visually,

```
f[x_] := (x^2 - 4)/(x - 2);

Manipulate[Module[{lim = Limit[f[x], x -> 2]},
  Plot[Tooltip[f[x]], {x, 2 - eps, 2 + eps},
   Epilog -> {Red, AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}],
     Line[{{2 - eps, lim}, {2, lim}, {2, f[2 - eps]}}]}]],
 {{eps, 1}, 10^(-Range[0., 5.]), ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]